# How to preserve NaNs in a pandas Series comparison?

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, nan, series

Say I have a series `s` with some `NaN`s:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan])

print(s)

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

and I want to perform a comparison operation, but preserving `NaN`s. For example, say I want to check equality of each element to `2`, producing:

```
0    False
1     True
2      NaN
dtype: object
```

But if I do `s == 2`, the `NaN` element evaluates to `False`:

```
print(s == 2)

0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A crude way would be to do a second pass through the equality check output and replace any rows where NaNs should be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan])

comp = s==2
comp[np.isnan(s)] = np.nan

print(comp)
```

```
0    False
1     True
2      NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

One method:

```
s.where((s==2) | (pd.isna(s)), other=False).replace(2, True)

0    False
1     True
2      NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice, although to be clear the equality comparison was just an example, I'm interested in a method for any comparison operator (e.g. `>`).

Comment: In that case, I would do @Mension1234's answer (but replace np.isna with pd.isna)